# Using @2x.png background images

Tags: css, retina

We are currently running a stylesheet on a different site with SVG and then PNG fallback.

Would this also work from retina images?

```
    background: url('/sfdt/mobile/images/template/sfdt-sprite_header-elements.png') -110px 0px / 190px no-repeat;
    background: url('/sfdt/mobile/images/template/sfdt-sprite_header-elements@X2.png') -110px 0px / 190px no-repeat;
```

Or would it be best to run this through the media queries like this?

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
  only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
  only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
```

Thanks

Daryl

Answer (score 0):

Normally the following line should work alone:

```
background: url('/sfdt/mobile/images/template/sfdt-sprite_header-elements@X2.png') -110px 0px / 190px no-repeat;
```

Comment: So there would be no need for a non retina image fall back? and non retina devices would view the image fine?

Comment: Yes, you don't need a fall back image because this image will be displayed on normal and on retina displays with the only difference that they are resized on normal displays but because the quality of the retina images is better, this doesn't affect the quality of your image